# Doctype and CSS

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have following code with doctype transitional but when I set it to strict then the position of images get changed and moves upward. Could you please help me in understanding the underlying issue and where I can find list of these type of other CSS conflicts between different doctypes.

Please note that I know that few HTML tags are not available in strict mode but I am specific about CSS conflicts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
span.check:before { content: url("http://i41.tinypic.com/2rxea7d.png"); }
</style>
<table> 
<tr>
<th>Ruby on Rails</th>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Road on Rails</th>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
    <td><span class="check"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: In FX 9.0.1 and latest Chrome but not sure about others.

Comment: doctype makes things case-sensible including the name of your id and classes and might explain why doctype mess-up your css

Answer (score 4):

In quirks mode and almost standards mode the images (which are inline content, so are laid out on the same set of lines as font characters) are [zero-height positioned at their baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko%27s_%22Almost_Standards%22_Mode).

You can get the same effect in Standards mode by twiddling the `vertical-align` property of your generated images or setting them as `display: block`.

Comment: I have put display: block; below content proper but it has not changed anything and difference between both doctypes remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that changing your doctype changes the mode that certain versions of internet explorer operate from standard mode to compatibility mode. Internet explorer (amongst other things) corrected how it interprets the border box model, but was able to switch between the old method and the corrected one depending on the DOCTYPE.